# How do I rerun Selenium 2.0 (webdriver) tests on the same browser?

Tags: java, authentication, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium 2.0 (Webdriver) to implement a series of tests.   Before these tests can run, I have to login into the application.  Since the application is not my 'own' (testing api-built functionality), each test should not be logging into my application to run.

I would prefer to do the following:

1. Connect my webdriver tests to my open Firefox browser (already loggedin)
2. Run my webdriver projects with the same browser.

I understand that Selenium usually assigns a session id to its browsers.  However, the current Java implementation of Selenium 2.0 driver does not make use of session id (maybe it does but I don't know where to find it. )

Can someone provide some direction on how to resolve my issue (existing browser and run multiple tests with Selenium 2.0 (java))?  Any code provided would also be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but if what you're trying to achieve is not having to re-login each time you run the tests, you might try setting the firefox profile. In selenium 1 you could use the -firefoxProfileTemplate "path to the profile" and set a specific firefox profile (this way it remembers the authentication cookies from one run to the another)

Comment: Thanks! I will try that method out.  Yes, I guess if I save the cookies and reuse them in each run, I would not have this problem.

Comment: This will help for getting the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690157/how-to-use-a-already-opened-firefox-for-testing-in-selenium Hope

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have learnt:

Selenium 1: As Ioan suggested earlier, use "-firefoxProfileTemplate" when starting up the Selenium RC server and point to the location of your Firefox profile.

Selenium 2: I suppose you can use the Selenium 1 RC server, however, since Selenium 2 uses WebDriver, you can point to the profile information within your code.

```
File profileDir = new File("/Users/_____/selenium/FFprofile");
FirefoxProfile profile =
new FirefoxProfile(profileDir);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(
    profile);
```

Notes:

1. Make sure you run "firefox -profilemanager" to create your initial profile and save your login information.
2. Allow the browser/website to always store your authentication credentials avoiding "popup"/"login" wwindows, etcs.

Hope this helps somebody who may run into a similar issue: Using the same browser profile in Selenium, etc.

Comment: Thanks Nivas, this just helped me.  There is also a FirefoxProfileManager that you can use to grab a collection of profiles, and then pass one of them to the FirefoxDriver constructor.  That would avoid hard-coding the file location