# How to autofill the user name and password in the pop up using selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver, autofill

How to auto fill the user name and password in the pop up using selenium in Linux(Ubuntu)

I am using selenium web driver to perform the automation tests for a web application. When I give the URL to the browser it immediately pop ups asking for username and password which I actually want to automate from the script. (This I want to do for Linux platform not for Windows)

Comment: What do you mean by pops up?It's a form or dialog?

Comment: Is this an HTTP auth popup you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I've never done it with Linux, but I'm assuming its the same.  Instead of typing `url.com/otherstuff/`, do `username:password@url.com/otherstuff/`

Comment: I have even tried that. It worked fine for chrome but not for Mozilla in windows platform. But my intention is to work on LINUX.So, in Linux I could not make it to work on Mozilla and Chrome. I know that it can be run on chrome on Linux.                                                              But How to implement the Chrome driver in Linux

Comment: Then I believe that this is the answer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151958/login-popup-window-using-selenium-webdriver