# How to get control to selenium web driver browser window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am developing the automation scripts for a web site using java selenium web driver.

But that web site is requesting for "Authentication required" (window) for two times.

I handled the first "Authentication required" window using modifying the URL like below

```
http://username:password@thaturl.com
```

But to handle second "Windows authentication", I dependent on multi processing.

I have done the following for handling second "Authentication required" window

```
Whenever the browser got stucks at "Authentication required" window, then I will be 
starting a small http server and opening a url, that opened url will type the username 
and password in the "Authentication required" window ( i.e. I am triggering another 
process through a url by creating handler for that url which will copy username and 
password in the "Authentication Required" window)
```

But my problem is that the web driver window is not getting on top of all other windows, so I am not able to copy username and password at exact place using robot object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using a robot? There's no way to reference the user/pass fields? For example, maybe this is a flash or java applet or something which selenium has really no support for.

Comment: for doing "ctrl v" which will copy username and password in to the boxes

Comment: Window looks like in below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151958/login-popup-window-using-selenium-webdriver.

Comment: Can I get any alternate to avoid robot object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AutoIT to automate window dialogs and for your scenario, you can actually bring a particular window into focus as well.

Here is one [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357634/seleniumautoit-script-to-handle-windows-authentication-pop-up-on-chrome), but there are lot of posts available on this topic.