# Handle login popup in selenium webdriver python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

How to handle the login pop up window using Selenium Webdriver? I am using Python language. I want to send the username and password. How to attain it.

I am getting below login prompt.

[image]

Comment: Redirecting you to already asked and answered question on SO: [Handle authentication dialogs with selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151958/login-popup-window-using-selenium-webdriver). Try either of the solutions given. If none works for you, give more details on this question.

Comment: Thanks the answered question was very useful