# WebDriver - how to get a page already open without modification

Tags: java, webdriver, awtrobot

I need to enter a protected website.
Security requires a username and password, but with graphical components of Windows (no web code, like upload a file for example).

To skip this step, I coded a small Awt.Robot, which find and valid the 'pop-up' windows.

So I am with a web page open in the expected state.

How can I regain control, from this state, with WebDriver?

some kind of :

> `​​driver FirefoxDriver = new FireFoxDriver();
>   driver.get (page already open without modification and authentification);`

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, it's not possible to take control of the already existing browser instance.

Some discussions:

[How to use a already opened firefox for testing in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690157/how-to-use-a-already-opened-firefox-for-testing-in-selenium)

Answer (score 1):

Getting around the JS popups is not easy and straightforward, using Robot solution is flaky. It will not work on Remote browsers etc.

Send username and password through url like `http://username:password@your-app.com`. Did you try something like below?

```
 String url = "http://username:password@your-app.com";
 driver.get(url);
```

Comment: I just tried http://username:password @ localhost / repository.
The web service told me that it is not necessary to authenticate and then a pop up appears. The same which I have a problem because it is not coded web. and yet I was able to skip this step by a robot (AWT.Robot)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you, nilesh, I had an idea. I write for anyone who might encounter the same difficulty. My solution is made ​​very simple, I instantiate my driver and just before the ***get(url)***, I run my ***AWT.Robot*** is now a Thread. This allows me to not be bothered by the blocking property of ***driver.get(url);***

```
private boolean openBrowserOnPage() {
        try {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            // run the robot which extends Thread
            RobotHabile robot = new RobotHabile();
            robot.start();
            // Open the browser
            driver.get(url);
                // Wait for robot action
            while(robot.isAlive()){
                // not much, wait
            }

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Erreur : Impossible de se connecter/acceder au service '" + url + "'");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Hoping to help someone

Comment: I am still wondering how this wil solve the issue? Can you please make me understand.

Comment: Ok I will try. My problem was a little bit specific : When I access to the deployed war, the browser (not the web page) ask me for an id and pwd. But without web component (OS component), so webDriver can't interact with.In addition, driver.get(url) is blocking. So I found myself with a popup for releasing the driver.get (url) method. Fortunately, the focus is automatically given to the first field (id).

Comment: So I used a class that inherits from Thread and implementing the Awt.Robot, I start() just before the driver.get(url). How the robot starts, wait a bit, id tap keyboard, press 'tab',type keyboard password, press 'enter', and kills himself. Suddenly pop up is enabled,I can access the web (local) site and driver.get(url) can finish his treatment.

Hoping for was clear.

Comment: Really sorry. I still could not understand the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For Purus, I will try again.

If I use `WebDriver.driver.get(http://localhost/repository);` the green popup appears, and that's all. The method will never finish. ***(1)***. This evil popup isn't a web component (not div, span, link, etc..) it's just a OS component (here Windows). It's impossible to manipulate this one with WebDriver.

So, just before `WebDriver.driver.get(http://localhost/repository);` I use a new class ***RobotHabile*** which extends ***Thread*** and use ***AWT.Robot***.
The ***AWT.Robot*** can use keyboard, so when the evil popup appears(***green***), the Thread 1 is waiting for validation of the popup and with my `RobotHabile robot = new RobotHabile();
 robot.start();`

With Thread 2 I can press my id, press tab for swith to password, press my pwd, and to finish press enter ***(2)*** .The robot does not target id and pwd fields. But as the popup already has focus, I can only fill with any character and tab key and enter. At this moment the evil popup is validate and the Thread 1 can normally continue.

[image: Explication of Threads execution]

better for your understanding ?