# Selenium c# : How to work with manually opened browser using selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to debug test scripts when ever failed. I dont want to run the entire test script from startng onwards (launching browser..logging )

If my browser already opened (manually)  and I would like to click on some objects (Web) , how can I achieve this programatically using selenium. I can do this in QTP but I dont know how can achieve this in selenium. Appreciate your quick help. !!

I am using Selenium 3.3 & IE 2.53 driver for Internet explorer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a already opened firefox for testing in Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690157/how-to-use-a-already-opened-firefox-for-testing-in-selenium)

Comment: By test scripts, do you mean Unit tests? By entire test script do you mean entire unit test or entire unit test suite?

Comment: I have gone through those threads but I am not getting want I need. All answers talking about execution wise and closing driver in test methods. But if I opened manually do i need to get that browser session id or something to access it. I dont know that

Comment: Giles, it does not matter. I am writing code in my console window for better debugging purpose. I just need to access a already opened browser (ex: manually ) and click on a button

Answer (score 1):

In general, the answer is that you can't do this. WebDriver explicitly does not support attaching to an existing browser instance that it did not start. This is a general principle, but is also explicitly true for Internet Explorer. I know that's not the answer you wanted to hear, but that's the way the IE driver is written at present.

Comment: Oh. is it. If not IE, can we do anything from Firefox and Chrome browsers?

Comment: @reachit Jim addressed this in his answer.

Comment: My Scenario is I  will launch Browser through WebDriver and will click on some objects and pages. Some where it failed and want to debug this. Is there any way where I can store any sessions or any information when I launched webdriver , so that I can reuse in my code snippet to go from there. I dont know I am able to explain correctly. please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problems. I work with an applications that has more than 10 screens.

We came up with a solution where we did not closed the browser if we encounter any failure. Have a solid exception handling in place and do not call Close() or Quit() methods to close the browser session.

Refer the below to come up with the program to continue automation with the already opened session. This is pretty much possible depending on how you designed your Automation framwork.

[How to use a already opened firefox for testing in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690157/how-to-use-a-already-opened-firefox-for-testing-in-selenium)

Work on firefox for debugging purposes and then you can run the same test with Internet explorer

Note : I will update the answer with C# program to work with existing browser instances.

Comment: I have seen this article, but not able to implement this in Selenium c# and also I am new to this. May be once I get the answer from you will implement. Thanks in advance !!